# bind value and text in textbox using ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a `TextBox` in which if I type any text values are fetched from database using AJAX and the result is displayed but I have to bind different value and text in `TextBox` on the basis of this AJAX data ie I have to display text from column `AcctName` and value from column `AcctName` but I'm unable to do this.

Here is my server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string partyname)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    DataTable dt;
    AccountInfo oAccount = new AccountInfo();
    dt = oAccount.GetAccountInfo((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["CompCode"], 0);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            result.Add(dt.Rows[i]["AcctCode"].ToString() + ";"+ result.Add(dt.Rows[i]["AcctName"].ToString() + ";"););
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="txtSearch" runat="server" class="autosuggest" style="min-width:100px;height:20px;" type="text" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });

    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "PurchaseOrder.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'partyname':'" + document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data.d);                
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what error did you have here. Do not let us guessing what is not working.

Comment: no it is working but the problem is that in this textbox dynamicaly adding li in ul but i have to bind li value to column name AcctCode and in text i have to bind AcctName ie i have use ; seperator to bind result or should i send u sample code for project

Comment: hey i have used your post  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data but how can i bind this value and description from ajax bcoz in this case it is assigned staticaly and i have to bind accname in desc and acccode in value in this labels so how can i bind it

Answer (score 0):

In case of `input` element of type `text` the text and value are the same thing and those can't be different.

You can take a look at this sample: [jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox). It shows how to customize Autocomplete in order to convert `select` element into `input` element with autocomplete functionality.

As an alternative you can modify this sample: [jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) in order to bind the value to the *data-** attribute and handle posting the proper value later manually.

When you choose your approach I might be able to help further.

**UPDATE**

You can take a look at this answer to get a sample solution for the second scenario: [jQuery AutoComplete multiple Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855617/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-output/12857110#12857110)