# jQuery AutoComplete multiple Output

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am using jQuery AutoComplete to fetch results from a DataBase based on the value inputted. The user will then click a search button to tell the page to search for that specific entries details.

I want to get 2 values, the **Name** and **Title**. I only want to display the **Name** to the user, while the page uses the **Title** as a search criteria.

eg: When a person types in **Vehicle**, the result will display `Vehicle1, Vehicle2` in a list.
When the user clicks on `Vehicle1`, a hidden box will be issues with the **Title**, which would be `Bike`, and such as with `Vehicle2`, which will issue the hidden box with `Car`.

I can get the **Name** to show in the text box properly, but I cannot for the life of me (And after 2 days of searching) bind the **Title** to a hidden box.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tb").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "AutoComplete.asmx/FetchEmailList",
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    //value: item.Title,
                                    label: item.Name
                                };
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
```

ASPX Code:

```
<div class="ui-widget" >
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAuto" class="tb" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbHidden" class="tb"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Employee> FetchEmailList(string prefix)
{
    var emp = new Employee();
    var fetchEmail = emp.GetEmployeeList(prefix)
    .Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(prefix.ToLower()));
    return fetchEmail.ToList();
}    
}
```

CompletionClass: (Excuse the naming)

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList(string prefixText)
    {
        List<Employee> cmpList = new List<Employee>();

        SqlConnection db = DataConn.SqlConnection();

        db.Open();
        SqlTransaction transaction = db.BeginTransaction();

        //var array = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [something] FROM vwGetDetails WHERE [something_else] LIKE N'%" + prefixText + "%' ORDER BY [thatOther_thing] ASC", db, transaction);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cmpList.Add(new Employee() { Name = reader["Value1"].ToString(), Title = "Value1_Cat", value = "Value1_Cat"});
                }
            }

            command = new SqlCommand("Select [something] FROM [somewhere] WHERE [thingy] LIKE N'%" + prefixText + "%' ORDER BY [previousThingy] ASC", db, transaction);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cmpList.Add(new Employee() { Name = reader["Value2"].ToString(), Title = "Value2_Cat", value = "Value2_Cat"});
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            cmpList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Problem Getting Results.", value = "Error"});
            //array.Add("Problem Getting Results.");
        }

        if (cmpList.Count == 0)
            cmpList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Nothing to Display.", value = "Info"});
        //array.Add("Nothing to Display.");

        //return array;

        return cmpList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those modifications to your JavaScript should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "AutoComplete.asmx/FetchEmailList",
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').val(ui.item.Name);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').val(ui.item.Name);
                $('input[name$="tbHidden"]').val(ui.item.Title);
                return false;
            }
        }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $('<li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + item.Name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
</script>
```

The assumption here is that the selectors returns exactly the element which we are working on, if not they need to be adjusted.

Comment: Sooo close! I have the 'hidden field' binding to a visible text box. The 'new text box shows the 'Name' (exactly as the old text box) instead of the title. EDIT: Added the .aspx page code..sorry.

Comment: Fixed it! I realised that the ID of the aspx controls changed :/ Should of thought of that sooner! I changed the class of the hidden control to td, and `$('.td').val(ui.item.Title);`... When can I get you a coffee?? :D

Comment: @NewAmbition After your update I have changed selectors to more exact ones so the answer will be more usable in future. In the subject of coffee - the mind exercise (and the points:>) is enough :).

Comment: how can i add scrollbars if content becomes large

Comment: @iProgrammer Such things qualify for separate questions, but as all what is requred is some CSS I'll post it here. Just use this CSS rule: `.ui-autocomplete { max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; }` (the value of `max-height` is the one to adjust here). P.S. You still haven't upvoted/accepted anything in this or your own question...

Comment: why this search is performing when i type atleast two character ie it is not  responding when i type only one alphabet search is not getting started

Comment: @iProgrammer Because `minLength` is set to 2, set it to 1 and it will search after 1 character

Comment: hey everything is fine but when i use second textbox and impliment the same thing  of same form it is not working due to  _delay: function( handler, delay ) the values are not showing in this textbox so whats the problem bcoz i have checked script everything is fine but when it goes in this function it is not displaying result

Comment: @iProgrammer I doubt we can solve this in comments (and we also shouldn't as this is not what comments are for). I need some more contex, source code etc.

Comment: i solved that issue but i have doubt that whether this focus and select works when i take another textbox and repeat the same functionality but with different data ie it is not working on second textbox ui does i have to pass id in these function

Comment: @iProgrammer I would really need to see some of your code - in general there should be no issues

Comment: @iProgrammer, would be nice if you upvoted the question and/or answers.

Comment: by clicking on the up-arrow above the number, or next to the comment.

Comment: @NewAmbition Justice have been served

Comment: @tpeczek did u understand the problem i have posted it in another question

Answer (score 0):

Cool. I've been googling for this solution for days... excellent clean code!
Just a small remark: using jqueryUI 1.10, this
throws javascript exception.
    `.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {...`
I've used
    `.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {...`
and everything works great.

Comment: Glad you could get a solution :)