# How to Map data in jquery-ui autocomplete is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery-ui autocomplete and making a  ajax call inside the autocomplete function i am calling my controller action which returns Json , but suggestions is not showing in dropdown

**Javascript**

```
 function log(message) {
            $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
            $("#log").scrollTop(0);
        }

        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetCompanyNames",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: "searchterm=" + request.term,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            alert(item.Value);
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                log(ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });

    });
```

**Action in Controller :**

```
    public JsonResult GetCompanyNames (string searchterm)
    {
        var companies = context.companyService.Query().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchterm)).ToList();
        var list = companies.Select(item => new SearchJsonModel
                                                {
                                                    LogoUrl = item.Logo != null || item.Logo != "" ? "<img  src='/Upload/" + item.Logo + "' />" : "<img src='/home/image?image=" + item.Name + "' />", Name = item.Name, Value = item.InternetName
                                                }).Select(model => (model)).ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**SearchJsonModel :**

```
 public class SearchJsonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**and this is what i am getting in response of ajax call ( this is the image of firebug )**

[image]

Please ask me if you need more detail and thanks in advance .

**Edit**

now i am trying to access selected value in select callback but its giving `Undefined`

```
select: function (event, ui) {
           alert(ui.item.Name);
                alert(ui.item.Value);
                alert(ui.item.LogoUrl);
        },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your `dataType` as `jsonp` but it looks like you are returning standard `json`, try changing your `dataType`:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetCompanyNames",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "searchterm=" + request.term,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.Name
                    };
                }));
            }});
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

Comment: and what is the difference between `Json` and `Jsonp` ?

Comment: @smartboy I do believe that Wikipedia explains it good enough: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: @smartboy This is a little bit more complicated, as the actual item from your response is not hold by autocomplete. In order to achieve that you need to override the internal `_renderItem` function. Please refer to following answer for a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855617/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-output/12857110#12857110 (don't forget to upvote with the up arrow on the left if the answer helps you).

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what is wrong in ur code but may be u can try another more simple way to do autocomplete? Like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[dataautocomplete]").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).attr("dataautocomplete"),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //do anything u need
                //get ur name  ui.item.Name
                //get ur URL   ui.item.LogoUrl
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html like

```
<input  class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="" name="post" dataautocomplete="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new { controller = "somecontroller", action = "someaction" })" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" />
```